# Java enum generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a class as below,

```
public class Baseclass {
   private final EmployeeEnum empEnum;
   public Baseclass(EmployeeEnum e) {
       this.empEnum = e;
    }
}
```

Now I want to make the Baseclass generic and make it accept Enums of a certain type.

Since Enum cant extend a class I have created an interface `IEnum` and made `EmployeeEnum` and `ManagerEnum`(the new enum I created) implement the interface.

I have made changes to Baseclass as below,

```
public class Baseclass {
   private final Enum<?> empEnum;
   public Baseclass(Enum<?> e) {
       this.empEnum = e;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you merely want **any** enum then you can use `E extends Enum<E>`.

```
public class Baseclass<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private final E e;

    public Baseclass(E e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}
```

All `enum`s extend `Enum<E>` so that they can inherit the standard methods such as `name` and `values`. This is one of the reasons why `enum`s cannot extend other classes because no `class` in Java is allowed to extend two classes.

Each sub-class must extend `BaseClass` with a specific enum like this:

```
enum MyEnum {

    I, Me, My, Mine;
}

class A extends BaseClass<MyEnum> {

    public A(MyEnum e) {
        super(e);
    }

}
```

If you want further restrictions - such as making subclasses only use enums of a special type (such as implementing an interface) then you can add the interface to the generic like this:

```
public interface SpecialEnum {

}

enum MyEnum implements SpecialEnum {

    I, Me, My, Mine;
}

enum NotSpecialEnum {

    Am, I, Special;
}

public class BaseClass<E extends Enum<E> & SpecialEnum> {

    private final E e;

    public BaseClass(E e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}

class A extends BaseClass<MyEnum> {

    public A(MyEnum e) {
        super(e);
    }

}

// This is not allowed.
class B extends BaseClass<NotSpecialEnum> {

    public A(NotSpecialEnum e) {
        super(e);
    }

}
```

You can even put the enum **inside** the extending class:

```
class A extends BaseClass<A.AnotherEnum> {

    enum AnotherEnum implements SpecialEnum {

        Hello, All;
    }

    public A(AnotherEnum e) {
        super(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I want Enums of a type. Like an interface IEnum.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Better way to do what? You could change to the code below which would limit you to enums that extend IEnum:

```
class Baseclass<T extends Enum<T> & IEnum> {
    private final T empEnum;
    public Baseclass(T e) {
        empEnum = e;
    }
}
```

So `T extends Enum<T>` - T must be an Enum 
`&` - and 
`IEnum` - `T` must extend `IEnum`.

Comment: Anyway other than modifying the class definition ? Just by changing the constructor signature?

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense to me. Why do you not want to change the class definition?

Comment: The class has other constructors which takes parameters other than Enums.

Comment: Your answer helped. Thanks!!